# WebViewCoreThread exception accessing strings.xml

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-webview

I having trouble accessing to strings.xml:

```
Log.i("url",context.getString(R.string.url));
```

in strings.xml

```
<string name="url">http://myip.com/</string>
```

It generates a exception:

```
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at com.usualbike.cbike.NewIncidence.noRegInsertData(NewIncidence.java:70)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at com.usualbike.cbike.IncidenceData$MyJavaScriptInterface.enviarIncidencia(IncidenceData.java:163)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:52)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1150)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:621)
12-12 14:52:44.551: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: you can also try as` getResources().getString(R.string.url);`

Comment: I cant. This class doesn't extends Activity

Comment: Oh!! i mean `context.getresources().getString(R.string.url);` and also use constructor of non activity class for initializing context variable instead of static

Comment: can i make it as answer?

Comment: if you did it, I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as to get String from `Strings.xml`

```
String strurl=context.getresources().getString(R.string.url);
Log.i("url ",strurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

`context` is `null`, apparently, if you are getting a `NullPointerException` on that line.

Comment: I think this isn't possible, I use context in the class and this is static

Comment: @user1256477: By definition it is possible, if you are getting a `NullPointerException` on that line. You should not be storing a `Context` in a static data member anyway. Pass a `Context` (such as the `Activity` hosting your `WebView`) into your `MyJavaScriptInterface` object via its constructor, hold onto it, and use it.